# Still Unauthenticated while permiting all requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am building my first project in Spring Boot. I used

```
.authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())
```

to permit all requests.

This is the full code:

```
package com.duong.backend.configs;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
        this.jwtAuthFilter = jwtAuthFilter;
    }

    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

But I still get 401 error when accessing a path:
[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: are you setting the Authentication object in spring security global context inside your jwtAuthFilter class ?